# When is contextDestroyed called?

Tags: java, tomcat, servletcontextlistener

Having implemented a `ContextListener` I can now happily deal with `contextDestroyed` events by closing down my connection pools and flushing my caches etc.

I was surprised recently when `contextDestroyed` was called at a time when my server was not being shut down - it seemed to be at some arbitrary time which I have not been able to track down.

Is there any defined event or set of circumstances that trigger `contextDestroyed`?

Should I ensure that everything I do when `contextDestroyed` is called is reversible? Do I need to make all my pools survive a `destroyed/initialized` cycle? Was I wrong to assume I would only get a `contextDestroyed` when Tomcat was being shut down or my `war` was being replaced?

Comment: I imagine it's `ServletContextListener` from the tags @Kayaman

Comment: Ah yea, I didn't look at the tags. The key here is that it really is `ServletContext` not `ServerContext`. While all the servlet contexts are surely destroyed when the server goes down, it doesn't mean that the servlet contexts couldn't be destroyed at other times (such as when left unused for a long time). Which server are you using? You may be able to control the destruction through parameters.

Comment: The `Servlet Lifecycle` allows the container to remove the context for example to reclaim resources, so better check if Tomcat allows you to control the behaviour.

Comment: ServletContext is "MyWebappContext" not just a single servlet. Its true in theory J2EE server could unload idling web application but I have not encountered any. You however may initiate webapp redeployment without restarting the application server. Edit mywebapp/web-inf/* files, admin panel restart click, copy or delete new mywebapp/web-inf/lib/*.jar file at runtime, delete webapps/mywebapp.war file or replace it. Most J2EE servers supports this kind of hot deployment.

Comment: @christopher - Yes, it is a `ServletContextListener`.

Comment: @Whome - If I delete the .war I get a `contextDestroyed` before Tomcat cleans up. Copying in a new .war cleanly starts everything up again and I survive that because all my singleton pools get recreated. My issue is that I now find I **can** (rarely) get a `contextDestroyed` without a refresh of my static data which causes all sorts of damage to the point where I have to restart Tomcat to recover.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Through a series of trial and error testing I have found that `contextDestroyed()` is called when;

1. The server is `.WAR` is being updated/removed.
2. The server is shutdown due to administrator intervention.
3. The server is shutdown due to a coding error. Something that would
   terminate a non-server application termination.

If you are experiencing issue #3, as you are suggesting, I think the best possible course of action is to safely (be sure not to create an infinite loop) call `contextInitialized()` to ensure pools are recreated properly.

Comment: Interesting point 3 - how did you cause that in your tests? Sadly my connection pools are not quick to create, it would be difficult to justify rebuilding them on `contextDestroyed` just in case.

Comment: Quite simply actually... I broke my code. I "intentionally" introduced a SQL query that could not complete, without a valid `ResultSet` it could not `next()` and threw a `NullPointerException` which in turn caused the program to terminate, without killing the Tomcat process. I'm going to assume your error isn't SQL related but these are my findings. I'm also going to assume that since this question is almost a year old that you have resolved the issue.

Comment: Actually I was unable to resolve it - it was a unique situation which I avoided. The problem boiled down to a classloader crash caused by bad library versions so I removed the dependency that was causing the issue. Thank you for your valuable experiences.

Comment: @glend In what way do you mean shutdown? by using ./catalina.sh stop in terminal? I havent had the chance to test outside eclipse setting. Im using a ServletContextListener with code run in context "initialized" and "destroyed." But the code in method "destroyed" doesnt seem to run when I actively stop the server (little red square pressed in eclipse). I know it runs when point 1 happens in your list: updated/removed. Because it writes out a simple sysout. Any thoughts on the reason? Is it perhaps the eclipse setting I have?

Comment: @brat, sorry its been so long since i did anything with tomcat. I don't remember. try creating another question or try posting something to a log.

Comment: @glend Thinking of starting a thread in listener that backs up data at regular intervals instead. Sidestepping the issue I have x). Thanks for reply, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

> contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce): Receives notification that
>   the ServletContext is about to be shut down.

I.e., it gets called when a web application gets unloaded (e.g., you remove or replace a .war file from the web-apps folder OR unload it using the Tomcat server-manager).

Comment: Thank you for your post but my question was about any **other** situations when `contextDestroyed` can be called. I was not able to reproduce the issue but from memory I saw `contextDestroyed` being called in a loop due to class loader exceptions in Tomcat. I cannot find any concrete contract that states exactly when `contectDestroyed` will be called - only the one you quote which specifies **one** situation and does not go any further.